# Do you ever need to write real code in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

Often I hear people around me who like to discussion about writing in assembly language and which is one of those reasons I'm also want to learn to write it. Currently I'm learning assembly and C together.

So, my question is when do you ever need to write assembly in real code?
Is it just good to learn?
Are there are any real uses of it when writing code in C?

Any helpful comments or answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Assembly isn't quite useful anymore IMO, but when it is, reading it is often more useful than writing it.

Comment: You'll need it anytime the compiler really doesn't cut it. Such as code dealing with video data, scientific simulation, some stuff in gaming especially if you're on a really tight cycle-budget, things mentioned by Bashwork, etc. It's less rare than some people make it out to be. It's rare in boring corporate apps that suck the life out of you when you write them.

Answer (score 8):

Despite the fact that writing code in assembly became increasingly rare, it is still very good to learn assembly simply to understand how things work under the hood. Modern optimizing compilers of C/C++ let you write code in C that translates into assembly instructions of very high quality, often surpassing what you could write manually at the expense of making the result less readable (e.g by inserting empty instructions to optimize the use of CPU's pipeline).

If you write a compiler for a new architecture, a very low-level library, or an embedded system with strict resource constraints, you may need to use assembly. For everything else, C and C++ will do as well or better.

Answer (score 5):

It's rare. I've never had to in 23 years + of career. But I work in the Client Server DB application space mainly, there are jobs where you'll use it a lot, or at least need to know how processors actually work.

However it was the first thing I learned, not counting basic digital electronics, and I'd say the learning has been a great help over my career and hobby programming.

Answer (score 5):

I was going to write a long post but decided to summarize instead:

1. embedded code, boot loaders, compiler backends
2. yes, it will help you understand and debug your compiled code
3. the only time I have used it in c is for reading the real time clock register

Answer (score 4):

Professional use of assembly language is quite common in the embedded world. There are lots of applications around us where microcontrollers do simple but useful things. For example, have a look at the [tinyAVR family of microcontrollers from Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/devices.asp?category_id=163&family_id=607&subfamily_id=791&source=left_nav), especially the ATtiny13 with its ridiculously small 1kB program memory and no RAM at all except for the 32 8-bit CPU registers. It's amazing though, what these chips are [capable of](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4-kF-MkP0A). That chip costs about one dollar when bought in large quantities. So when you produce a large quantity of a device that needs simple (or even not quite simple) logic, the savings in hardware production costs far outweigh the overhead of hand-crafting the code in assembler to make it work on an extremely limited platform.

Answer (score 3):

I had many occasions when I needed to write asm code at work, where in C either you couldn't do certain things at all (e.g. access special CPU registers or use CPU's system instructions), or compiled C code was too slow or too big (the compiler wasn't good enough).

Still, the fraction of the asm code or time spend writing it was pretty insignificant.

Learning asm is good. It makes you "see" through your C code, predict what instructions and how many it turns into, roughly estimate speed of parts of code. In the process you learn a number of optimization and other tricks and a few cool algorithms/methods that you can then transfer into your C code. Just look at those numerous questions about C pointers or conversion of numbers between binary and decimal or arbitrary precision arithmetic. Knowing asm helps with these and other things.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it twice in 2011 so far, and I mostly work on Java line of business apps.  Came in handy for whipping up a quick setup.exe to wrap a JRE and app install.  Could have done that in C, but it's quicker to grab and setup an assembler than a compiler and for such a simple app the write time is comparable either way...  Also used it to work on a problem interfacing with a USB device.  Was failing for unknown reasons via JNA, so I wrote it in assembly to make sure I knew where every bit was going and when.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we absolutely still code in assembly on a daily basis.  We don't sit down and write entire programs in assembly - we just provide assembly language kernel functions that accelerate high performance code.

The reason this is necessary is there is an ever widening gap between the way compilers imagine machines work and the way they do.  In particular, for modern systems, data movement is vastly more important to performance than computation.  But compilers are still rooted in an age when SpecInt was important and tend to regard data movement as a logical no-op.

The single largest reason we have to use assembly language instead of intrinsics is register allocation.  Compilers are terrible at register blocking, or understanding which data is being stored in which caches. To a compiler, all cache misses are considered equivalent in cost, and often the compiler has no sense how you're using the data dynamically or where it is.

Ironically, even without register blocking, this is why compilers seldom achieve SIMD performance benefits even though they're good at emitting SIMD code for computation - they always tend to botch things on the "I/O" end - that is, when the SIMD information needs to be read and written from memory.

Now, if you're writing the kind of code that is more declarative instead of imperative, that is, your job is specifying what to do and not how to do it - well - that was what compilers were made for.  That's a good match.

As a brief aside, there are people who focus on getting as close to assembly language performance as possible using C, due to the portability benefits.  An example of the tricks they use is they restrict a function to only use less variables than available registers on the machine - that way, the compiler won't spill any variables, and proper register allocation is moot, because everything just stays in registers. When this type of coding is possible, you can achieve 75%-90% of assembly language performance, although typically at a much higher power cost, due to the emission of far more instructions than needed.  As you might expect, the more cores you employ, and the more data intensive the task, the farther behind C performance gets from assembly language.

Comment: In my experience GCC and Clang generally do fine at register allocation with SSE or AVX intrinsics for x86-64.  And recently also somewhat ok with AVX-512 `k` mask registers.  Intrinsics in C are low enough level that you have fairly good control of where you're loading from and storing to within a loop, and x86-64 asm doesn't give you more control of caches on a per-load basis.  So I'm curious what kind of systems you're programming where this is a big problem, and where you can't get a compiler to make good asm.

Comment: One case I can think of where compilers destroyed performance with x86 intrinsics was reordering some `movnt` stores so they didn't make contiguous full-line writes as often.  (*[Wrong gcc generated assembly ordering, results in performance hit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25778302)*).  Other than that, compiler missed-optimizations are frequent but relatively minor (e.g. using indexed addressing modes even when unrolling, resulting in un-lamination to 2 uops on Intel CPUs, or missing tricks like indexing one array relative to the other to avoid that.)

Comment: For 32-bit ARM, compilers are or were terrible at partial register stuff (the `d` halves of a `q` vector) so hand-written asm is still important there, but I hadn't heard of big speedups vs. what they could get a compiler to emit with intrinsics on other mainstream platforms.  And BTW, this question is tagged [x86], although answers for another ISA would still be interesting.